# ¿Por qué se dice "bajar la santamaría"?

Tags: modismos, idiomático, venezuela

Creo que *bajar la Santamaría* significa *cerrar una tienda*.

¿Por qué se dice así?

Comment: Serrar significa cortar con sierra. En tu caso debes usar Cerrar con C

Comment: Parece que es una expresión para [echarse a dormir o descansar](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080115212325AAKZNDY) (o cerrar una tienda para la siesta?). No puedo citar referencias, pero a mi me suena a término náutico. No sé si hay una "vela santamaría" o similar que se quite al anclar una barco. La Santa María era el barco insignia de Colón, que quedó en mal estado tras el viaje y fue despedazado para construir el Fuerte Navidad. Ahora, no hay razón para pensar que esté relacionado con la expresión.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por lo que he visto, es una expresión propia de Venezuela, donde por alguna razón que desconozco, a las cortinas enrollables metálicas las llaman "puertas Santa María", como puede verse en [este libro](https://books.google.com/books?id=7QtTX3HNC-kC&pg=PA62&dq=%22bajar%20la%20santamar%C3%ADa%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bajar%20la%20santamar%C3%ADa%22&f=false) o en tiendas online de Venezuela.

Comment: Tal vez hubiera alguna fábrica de persianas llamada así. No es raro que el nombre de una marca termine denominando el producto (*celo*, *típex*, *rímel*, *clínex*...) ¿Algún venezolano puede echarnos una mano?